# Black bars only showing up on iOS 6+ simulator builds

Tags: ios, iphone

I'm trying to figure out why I am encountering two black bars up and below the simulator only on iOS 6 simulators and up. On iOS 5 simulator it looks great but for w/e reason it is doing these weird black boxes on top and bottom of my app. I've figured out that when I add a launch screen file that the black bars do disappear but many other elements on my app are out of place which won't work. So ideally I am looking to get rid of these black boxes on iPhone 6 and up as well as keeping my elements in the right area. Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Sounds like you don't have a Launch Screen File. You need that to support all screen sizes. Don't use launch images any more.

Comment: If I use the existing storyboard as a launch screen file the app area retreats up to be a much smaller version of the app up top.

Comment: I'm telling you what you need. That's a separate issue.